# File read write error while in mapFragment.init method

Tags: android, sdk

I am using the premium version of the android SDK. I have created app using this SDK and it is working perfectly on the android tablets like Acer Tablet, Nexus Tablet.

But now i am tring to run the APK on the new device Fusion5 Tablet  (http://www.fusion5store.com/us), It is giving me FILE_RW_ERROR error message ("SDK cache is missing."). When i debug it it's throwing the error in init method on  onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error).

I already gave the Storage permission.
It's strange that my app can save the photos and all which works completely fine but Here map is not loading.
Please help.

Comment: Can you do a 'adb shell', then 'ls /sdcard' ? Is the SD card folder present on the device? And what does Context#getExternalFilesDir() return?

Comment: @RohanB Did you find the solution for this? Please do update here, I am also facing same issue.

Comment: I'm having this same issue.

Comment: @RohanB, which Android SDK release are you currently using where this issue is occurring?

Comment: Same question to @GeekWithGlasses

Comment: Same question to @Gagege

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport Sorry, it turns out my issue was unrelated, but similar to this one.